# Set precision in Haskell

Tags: haskell, precision

I am having a code that take input T and followed by T lines. I want to set precision to 12 decimal places. How can I increase precision in Haskell?

Code:

```
f i=(-1)**i/(2*i+1) 
g j=show$sum$map f[0..j-1]
p(_:l)=map(g.read)l
main=interact$unlines.p.lines
```

Like if input is:

```
1
10
```

Then output is 0.7604599047323508, but I want only 0.760459904732.

Comment: Please don't edit your question so as to make the existing answer look like nonsense.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `printf` from Text.Printf

```
printf "%.12f" 0.7604599047323508
```

`printf` is overloaded so you need to specify the return type but you can do:

```
showPrec :: Double -> String
showPrec = printf "%.12f"
```

then you can replace the use of `show` in `g`:

```
g j = showPrec $ sum $ map f[0..j-1]
```

you can use `printf` directly in `g` if you specify the type:

```
g :: Double -> String
g j = printf "%.12f" $ sum $ map f[0..j-1]
```

Comment: Where to add this line ?

Comment: Erm, actually it doesn't seem necessary in this case.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I didnt get you

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen But now I am getting compile time error in my code. I am not able to edit my code

Comment: You also need `import Text.Printf` at the top.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Yeah i had done that. And will g function be like this : g j=printf "%.12f" $sum$map f[0..j-1]

Comment: @Lee Can't it be done in g function only instead of making different function ?

Comment: @user3786422 Oh I see, my deleted comment was right anyhow, sigh, it's just that the whole file somehow loaded for me in GHCi. I think Lee's extra function is simplest, then.

Comment: @Lee Can't it be done in g function only instead of making different function ? I want to minimise the characters used in my code

Comment: @Lee Can we merge f function in g also ?? Or f with p ? I want to minimise the size of code

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Instead of making separate f function can that f function me merged in g only ?

Comment: @user3786422 Ah golfing... ``g j=printf"%.12f"$sum[(-1)**i/(2*i+1)::Double|i<-[0..j-1]]
``

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Yeah..:) And what about P function ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70915/discussion-between-orjan-johansen-and-user3786422).

Answer (score 2):

The main question is whether you want more accurate presentation or more accurate numbers.
See @Lee's answer for `printf` if you're more concerned about presentation.

## Arbitrary Precision

If you want numbers that are (arbitrarily) more accurate than `Double` or `Float`, use `Scientific` offered by the scientific package. Note the `Integer` type already has arbitrary precision.

Scientific numbers can be written as literals, they only need type annotations:

```
> let d = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510 :: Scientific
> :t d
d :: Scientific
```

#### Scientific -> String

```
> formatScientific Exponent (Just 3) d
"3.142e0"

> formatScientific Generic (Just 3) d
"3.142"

> formatScientific Generic (Just 100) d
"3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

> formatScientific Generic (Just 16) d
"3.1415926535897932"
```

#### Float -> Scientific

```
> fromFloatDigits 3.1415
3.1415
```

#### String -> Scientific

```
> read "1e1000000000" :: Scientific
1.0e1000000000
```

#### General use

You only need to specify the type of one of your numbers as `Scientific`. After this, you can simply write literals and use Numeric, Floating and RealFrac function as usual. Note `/` might diverge if the representation has infinite decimals. [See the documentation for more details.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific)

```
> d / 2
1.57079632679489661923132169163975144209858469968755

> (d * 1000000000) + 1 == 1000000000 * (d + 1/1000000000)
True
```